# Populating data from Edittext input to Spinner Display using Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

Expert Please advise with following my query.
I am trying to run the query in Android studio .

As is : Spinner shows the  X value as per edittext X value input using Textwatcher.

To be : Spinner should show the Y value as per X value input in Edit text.

Example: If i enter value "6" in edittext then my spinner should show the vaue "Data Structures"

My Database follows.[image]

Database follows

```js
package com.bar.example.myapplication;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private Context mContext;

  //TASK: DEFINE THE DATABASE VERSION AND NAME  (DATABASE CONTAINS MULTIPLE TABLES)
  static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OCC";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  //TASK: DEFINE THE FIELDS (COLUMN NAMES) FOR THE COURSES TABLE
  public static final String COURSES_TABLE = "Courses";
  public static final String COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID = "_id";
  public static final String FIELD_ALPHA = "alpha";
  public static final String FIELD_NUMBER = "number";
  public static final String FIELD_TITLE = "title";

  //TASK: DEFINE THE FIELDS (COLUMN NAMES) FOR THE INSTRUCTORS TABLE


  //TASK: DEFINE THE FIELDS (COLUMN NAMES) FOR THE OFFERINGS TABLE
  private static final String OFFERINGS_TABLE = "Offerings";
  private static final String OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID = "crn";
  private static final String FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE = "semester_code";
  public static final String FIELD_COURSE_ID = "course_id";

  public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mContext = context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + COURSES_TABLE + "(" +
      COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
      FIELD_ALPHA + " TEXT, " +
      FIELD_NUMBER + " TEXT, " +
      FIELD_TITLE + " TEXT" + ")";
    database.execSQL(createQuery);



    createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + OFFERINGS_TABLE + "(" +
      OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
      FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE + " INTEGER, " +
      FIELD_COURSE_ID + " INTEGER, "

      +
      "FOREIGN KEY(" + FIELD_COURSE_ID + ") REFERENCES "

      +
      COURSES_TABLE + "(" + COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + ")" +
      ")";
    database.execSQL(createQuery);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,
    int oldVersion,
    int newVersion) {
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + COURSES_TABLE);

    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + OFFERINGS_TABLE);
    onCreate(database);
  }

  //********** COURSE TABLE OPERATIONS:  ADD, GETALL, EDIT, DELETE

  public void addCourse(Course course) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FIELD_ALPHA, course.getAlpha());
    values.put(FIELD_NUMBER, course.getNumber());
    values.put(FIELD_TITLE, course.getTitle());

    db.insert(COURSES_TABLE, null, values);

    // CLOSE THE DATABASE CONNECTION
    db.close();
  }

  public ArrayList < Course > getAllCourses() {
    ArrayList < Course > coursesList = new ArrayList < > ();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(queryList, null);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
      COURSES_TABLE,
      new String[] {
        COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID,
        FIELD_ALPHA,
        FIELD_NUMBER,
        FIELD_TITLE
      },
      null,
      null,
      null, null, null, null);

    //COLLECT EACH ROW IN THE TABLE
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        Course course =
          new Course(cursor.getInt(0),
            cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3));
        coursesList.add(course);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return coursesList;
  }

  public void deleteCourse(Course course) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // DELETE THE TABLE ROW
    db.delete(COURSES_TABLE, COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + " = ?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(course.getId())
      });
    db.close();
  }

  public void deleteAllCourses() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(COURSES_TABLE, null, null);
    db.close();
  }

  public void updateCourse(Course course) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FIELD_ALPHA, course.getAlpha());
    values.put(FIELD_NUMBER, course.getNumber());
    values.put(FIELD_TITLE, course.getTitle());

    db.update(COURSES_TABLE, values, COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + " = ?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(course.getId())
      });
    db.close();
  }

  public Course getCourse(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
      COURSES_TABLE,
      new String[] {
        COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID,
        FIELD_ALPHA,
        FIELD_NUMBER,
        FIELD_TITLE
      },
      COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID + "=?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(id)
      },
      null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
      cursor.moveToFirst();

    Course course = new Course(
      cursor.getInt(0),
      cursor.getString(1),
      cursor.getString(2),
      cursor.getString(3));

    db.close();
    return course;
  }




  //********** OFFERING TABLE OPERATIONS:  ADD, GETALL, EDIT, DELETE

  public void addOffering(int crn, int semesterCode, int courseId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID, crn);
    values.put(FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE, semesterCode);
    values.put(FIELD_COURSE_ID, courseId);


    db.insert(OFFERINGS_TABLE, null, values);

    // CLOSE THE DATABASE CONNECTION
    db.close();
  }

  public ArrayList < Offering > getAllOfferings() {
    ArrayList < Offering > offeringsList = new ArrayList < > ();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(queryList, null);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
      OFFERINGS_TABLE,
      new String[] {
        OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID,
        FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE,
        FIELD_COURSE_ID
      },
      null,
      null,
      null, null, null, null);

    //COLLECT EACH ROW IN THE TABLE
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        Course course = getCourse(cursor.getInt(2));
        //Instructor instructor = getInstructor(cursor.getInt(3));
        Offering offering = new Offering(cursor.getInt(0),
          cursor.getInt(1), course);

        offeringsList.add(offering);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return offeringsList;
  }

  public void deleteOffering(Offering offering) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // DELETE THE TABLE ROW
    db.delete(OFFERINGS_TABLE, OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID + " = ?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(offering.getCRN())
      });
    db.close();
  }

  public void deleteAllOfferings() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(OFFERINGS_TABLE, null, null);
    db.close();
  }

  public void updateOffering(Offering offering) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE, offering.getSemesterCode());
    values.put(FIELD_COURSE_ID, offering.getCourse().getId());


    db.update(OFFERINGS_TABLE, values, OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID + " = ?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(offering.getCRN())
      });
    db.close();
  }

  public Offering getOffering(int crn) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
      OFFERINGS_TABLE,
      new String[] {
        OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID,
        FIELD_SEMESTER_CODE,
        FIELD_COURSE_ID
      },
      OFFERINGS_KEY_FIELD_ID + "=?",
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(crn)
      },
      null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
      cursor.moveToFirst();

    Course course = getCourse(cursor.getInt(2));
    //Instructor instructor = getInstructor(cursor.getInt(3));
    Offering offering = new Offering(cursor.getInt(0),
      cursor.getInt(1), course);


    db.close();
    return offering;
  }

  public Cursor getAllLabelsAsCursor() {
    String[] columns = new String[] {
      "rowid AS _id, *"
    }; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(COURSES_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
  }



  public boolean importCoursesFromCSV(String csvFileName) {
    AssetManager manager = mContext.getAssets();
    InputStream inStream;
    try {
      inStream = manager.open(csvFileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    String line;
    try {
      while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        if (fields.length != 4) {
          Log.d("OCC Course Finder", "Skipping Bad CSV Row: " + Arrays.toString(fields));
          continue;
        }
        int id = Integer.parseInt(fields[0].trim());
        String alpha = fields[1].trim();
        String number = fields[2].trim();
        String title = fields[3].trim();
        addCourse(new Course(id, alpha, number, title));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }



  public boolean importOfferingsFromCSV(String csvFileName) {
    AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
    InputStream inStream = null;
    try {
      inStream = am.open(csvFileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    String line;
    try {
      while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        if (fields.length != 4) {
          Log.d("OCC Course Finder", "Skipping Bad CSV Row: " + Arrays.toString(fields));
          continue;
        }
        int crn = Integer.parseInt(fields[0].trim());
        int semesterCode = Integer.parseInt(fields[1].trim());
        int courseId = Integer.parseInt(fields[2].trim());

        addOffering(crn, semesterCode, courseId);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

main activity.

```js
package com.bar.example.myapplication;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CourseSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private DBHelper db;
  private List < Course > allCoursesList;
  private List < Offering > allOfferingsList;
  private List < Offering > filteredOfferingsList;
  public Button reset;
  private EditText courseTitleEditText;
  private Spinner ok;
  private ListView offeringsListView;

  // private selectedInstructorName selectedInstructorName;
  private InstructorSpinnerAdapter instructorSpinnerAdapter;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_search);

    deleteDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.importCoursesFromCSV("courses.csv");

    db.importOfferingsFromCSV("offerings.csv");
    Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    allOfferingsList = db.getAllOfferings();
    filteredOfferingsList = new ArrayList < > (allOfferingsList);

    allCoursesList = db.getAllCourses();

    courseTitleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.courseTitleEditText);
    courseTitleEditText.addTextChangedListener(courseTitleTextWatcher);

    ok = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


    // offeringListAdapter = new OfferingListAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);
    // ok.setAdapter(offeringListAdapter);
    instructorSpinnerAdapter = new InstructorSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.offering_list_item, filteredOfferingsList);

    ArrayAdapter < String > instructorSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String >
      (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getAllCourse());
    ok.setAdapter(instructorSpinnerAdapter);

    ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(instructorSpinnerListener);


  }


  private String[] getAllCourse1() {
    String[] instructorNames = new String[allCoursesList.size() + 1];
    instructorNames[0] = "[Select Course]";
    for (int i = 1; i < instructorNames.length; i++) {
      instructorNames[i] = allCoursesList.get(i - 1).getTitle();
    }
    return instructorNames;
  }



  private ArrayList < String > getAllCourse() {
    ArrayList < String > instructorNames = new ArrayList < > ();
    instructorNames.add("[Select Course]");
    for (int i = 0; i < allCoursesList.size(); i++) {

      instructorNames.add(allCoursesList.get(i).getTitle());
    }
    return instructorNames;
  }

  public TextWatcher courseTitleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
      String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
      ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) ok.getAdapter();
      adapter.clear();
      if (input.equals("")) {
        adapter.addAll(getAllCourse());
      } else {
        Course course;
        for (int j = 0; j < allCoursesList.size(); j++) {
          // If the course title starts with the user input,
          // add it to the listAdapter
          course = allCoursesList.get(j);
          if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {
            adapter.add(course.getTitle());
          }
        }
      }
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      if (adapter.getCount() != 0) ok.setSelection(0);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


    }
  };

  public AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener instructorSpinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
      String selectedInstructorName = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
      if (selectedInstructorName.equals("[Select Instructor]")) {
        instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();
        for (Offering offering: allOfferingsList)
          instructorSpinnerAdapter.add(offering);


      } else {

        instructorSpinnerAdapter.clear();

      }

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > adapterView) {
      adapterView.setSelection(0);

      // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Why?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  };




}
```

Activity_course_search.xml

```js
<< ? xml version = "1.0"
encoding = "utf-8" ? >
  <
  LinearLayout
xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android: id = "@+id/activity_course_search"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: orientation = "vertical"
android: paddingBottom = "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android: paddingLeft = "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android: paddingRight = "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android: paddingTop = "@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools: context = "com.bar.example.myapplication.CourseSearchActivity" >

  <
  LinearLayout
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content" >

  <
  TextView
android: text = "Filter By  Instructor"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: id = "@+id/textView" /
  >

  <
  Spinner
android: id = "@+id/instructorSpinner"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1" / >

  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  LinearLayout
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content" >

  <
  TextView
android: text = "Filter By Course Title"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: id = "@+id/textView2" /
  >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/courseTitleEditText"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: inputType = "textPersonName"
android: ems = "10" /
  >

  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  LinearLayout
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content" >

  <
  Button
android: text = "@string/reset_button_text"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: id = "@+id/resetButton" /
  >

  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  ListView
android: id = "@+id/offeringsListView"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "18dp" >

  <
  /ListView>

  <
  Spinner
android: id = "@+id/spinner1"
android: layout_width = "341dp"
android: layout_height = "93dp"
android: layout_weight = "1" / >
  <
  /LinearLayout>
```

offering_list_item.xml

```js
<< ? xml version = "1.0"
encoding = "utf-8" ? >
  <
  LinearLayout xmlns : android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"

android: id = "@+id/offeringListLinearLayout" >

  <
  LinearLayout
android: orientation = "vertical"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent" >

  <
  TextView
android: text = "TextView"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: textSize = "20sp"
android: id = "@+id/offeringListFullNameTextView" / >


  <
  /LinearLayout>


  <
  /LinearLayout>
```

Main Screen 1 : 
[image]

Requirement 1 : (Working Fine) spinner selection from database.

[image]

Requirement 2 : Working but need in another way . Spinner display from database based on edittext entry using textwacher.  What i want is that if enter "Number A170 then my spinner should show "title" Java Programming 1 from database

Current screen shows [image]

I want it in this way ... 
[image]

revised onTextChanged code.

```js
public TextWatcher courseTitleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

  }
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    String input = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) ok.getAdapter();
    adapter.clear();
    if (input.equals("")) {
      adapter.addAll(getAllCourse());
    } else {
      Course course;

      for (int j = 0; j < CoursesList.size(); j++) {
        // If the course title starts with the user input,
        // add it to the listAdapter
        // course = allCoursesList.get(j);
        if (courseTitleEditText.getText().equals(CoursesList.get(j).get("number"))) {
          //adapter.add(course.getTitle());
          ok.setSelection(j);

        }
      }
    }
    // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //if(adapter.getCount() != 0)
    // ok.setSelection(i);
  }
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


  }
};
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, what will your layout looks like, I assume it won't be anything like the database representation you've shared. 
Will you have an edittext and a spinner separated or something like an autocomplete textview that gives you suggestions according to what you're inputting in. Finally, will you be inputting the id each time? In that case why use a spinner?

Comment: Ok after reading a little more, what you are trying to achieve is an `ACTV (autocompletetextview)`. You input a value, on change you look in your list, and then you add to matching courses to the spinner. The only difference with an ACTV (as far as I have done) is that you won't get any result until you start typing, as in your views, your spinner will be filled with all results when you type nothing

Comment: I'll post it as a comment as it is not what you request but here are some tutorials that might help you
Basic example : 
https://www.journaldev.com/9574/android-autocompletetextview-example-tutorial

SQLite example :
https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-autocompletetextview-example-sqlite-database/

If this is what you expected tell me and I'll put it as an answer so everyone facing the same issue might see it directly :)

Comment: @MatthieuMeunier Thanks for your feedback details attached...

Comment: I just saw your revised `onTextChanged`, I don't think you'll get any results until you *erase* the text in your `EditText`. Because you get all courses when the *changed text* is empty but will the callback be called directly or only after typing, which I believe, and so if you type something your text won't be empty anymore, thus not loading the courses, but if you erase your text it will be empty, and then, load the courses, making it possible to get through your courses. I would recommend to get all courses in `onCreate` or even in `onResume`

Comment: so if you get any modification while leaving your activity you'll get the changes reflected in your list :)

Comment: Hi @MatthieuMeunier..i am facing challange were displaying course title in spinner based on edittext typing "course no" which should match course title

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should solve your issue.

Replace `if (course.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {`

with `if (course.getNumber().toLowerCase().startsWith(input)) {`.

Answer (score 0):

i think i figure what do you need

actully it's little simple
im try to work it with your code but not by modeling way like you 
it will be by hashmap array

first we need to get the data from you sqlite by using this code

**THIS in class DBHelper**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
```

this the import you need here

```
public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> getCourses()
{
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("select * from " + COURSES_TABLE, null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datanum.put("id", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID)));
        datanum.put("alpha", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(FIELD_ALPHA)));
        datanum.put("number", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(FIELD_NUMBER)));
        datanum.put("title", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(FIELD_TITLE)));
        array_list.add(datanum);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

this code here will work perfect with you not need to edit i make it with your class

now you need to call this method in you class

**THIS in class CourseSearchActivity**

```
DBHelper DB;
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> CoursesList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

on create

```
    DB = new DBHelper(this);
    CoursesList= DB.getCourses();
```

now you have all in your CoursesList now you need to figure out which spinner position you wanna to select it

so

you going to loop on it

**THIS in Textlistener**

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < CoursesList.size() ; i++){
        if(courseTitleEditText.getText().equals(CoursesList.get(i).get("number"))){//ex.A170
// you must to be filled your spinner from same courses db and here you gonna to set your selection by iteration
            ok.setSelection(i);
        } 
    }
```

maybe it's not the right thing to your code because i see you use modeling in your code and i use Hashmap but i think it's useful to see the same way in your modeling from this code
i didn't test it i wrote it direct so test and told me what happen
hope i help

Comment: hi thanks i am trying with your code.. Stuck in loop . can you advise where to add this code ?  i mean looping code ....is this "private ArrayList<String> getAllCourse() {"

Comment: put the loop on your onTextChanged 
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> CoursesList
this will have all courses as arraylist hashmap work it with id and key with value 

the function in DB it's different than arraylist<string> getallcourse 

set it under it or in the same class DB

Comment: it's oki mate , the bad think that im sure from this code will work but i can't check it with your screen or debug ,.. anyway hope you got it brother

Comment: Mate i am keep trying with your code for a desired result. Revised code attached. let me know what went wrong...

Comment: is it allow to connect with u remotely ? or this not allow in stackoverflow because i can't find something about this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170587/discussion-between-leace-and-hassan-badawi).